# What did Isabel whisper to Matsui in the interrogation room scene in Ocean's Twelve?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, oceans-twelve

In the interrogation room scene in Ocean's Twelve, a police officer is questioning Matsui when Isabel enters the scene. After some dialog Matsui breaks down crying.

What could Isabel possibly have whispered in his ear for him to break down crying?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## It was purposefully left ambiguous.

The scene was meant to show that Isabel is a strong character and knows what she's doing. From the script,

```
  They shrug. Isabel goes into the room with Evelyn. We STAY
  WITH Onderdonk and Davenpeck, who watch her through the two-
  way mirror.

  THROUGH THE MIRROR: Isabel walks right up to Evelyn, smiles,
  and whispers one word to him/her.

  Evelyn's face freezes. He/she looks at Isabel, scared. Then
  he/she starts to weep. Uncontrollably.... Tears stream down
  his/her face.

  Isabel hands Evelyn a sheet of paper and he/she begins to
  write.

  Onderdonk and Davenpeck are dumbfounded.     Isabel turns
  around so she's facing them.
```

So, all that we know is that it was a single word, but we are never told what that word was.

Comment: Why is it "Evelyn" and "he/she"?

Comment: @BruceWayne earlier script?

Comment: yeah I guess so. Neat to see they did that, I always assumed they'd at least know the sex of a character, but I guess they left it up to casting

Comment: speculation, but maybe she had done her homework on Matsuii, and knew a word that was a "trigger" for a painful memory or something very dear to him, that if captured by the police, would bring him down hard. A mere mention of the word was enough to break him.